# Passing attributes between Jade mixins

Tags: pug

When creating a jade mixin such as:

```
mixin form()
    form(
        id=attributes.id,
        class=attributes.class
    )
        block
```

then extending like so:

```
mixin form-horizontal()
    +form.form-horizontal(
        id=attributes.id,
        class=attributes.class
    )
        block
```

How do you pass the attributes to the base mixin from the inherited mixin so that you can write this instead?

```
mixin form-horizontal()
    +form.form-horizontal
        block
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass the attributes variable:

```
mixin form()
    form(attributes)
        block

mixin form-horizonal()
    form.form-horizontal(attributes=attributes)
        block
```

Thanks to http://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/